# UIWebView goBack crashing

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have the following setup

```
webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

Occasionally I issue the method

```
[webview goBack];
```

and this sometimes brings my app down in flames with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS). I tried to wrap this around a @try:

```
@try
{
    [webview goBack];
}
@catch (id theEx)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", theEx);
}
```

but this still brings tears of grief.

Is there a way I can make sure it does not crash? Perhaps checking if I can in fact go back?

Comment: There is no crash message. I find it from the crash log when I run on the device. Also, it's quite rare which makes it hard to see precisely what's wrong (heisenbug perhaps?).

Comment: Can you post the crash log then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually means that webview was somehow dealloc'd. Why are you using [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds]? You should use Interface Builder or set the frame to the superview's bounds. You're adding the view to a superview controlled by a view controller, right?

Comment: However, it seems you hit onto something. The way i created webview might have gotten it released somehow. I put a followup question as [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747906/why-does-apple-create-its-views-this-way)